# Match text surrounded by underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to match:

`_Sample welcome text_`  or `Sample _welcome_ _text_`

**but not** `Sample_welcome_text`

i.e there can be (space or  nothing) before the opening underscore and (space or nothing) after the closing underscore.

I have tried using this:

`/_(?:(?! ))(.*?)[^ ]_/gmi`

Though it works but unfortunately it matches `Sample_welcome_text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use lookbehind and lookahead assertion for searching text which surrounded by underscores, and there can be (space or nothing/start of string) before the opening underscore, (space or nothing/end of string) after the closing underscore.

```
/(?<=[ ]+|^)_(.*?)_(?=[ ]+|$)/gmi
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/t41Fkm/1

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alternation to either start with optional whitespace chars followed by an underscore, or the other way around.

Note that `\s` can also match newlines. You could match mere spaces instead if that is required, or `[^\S\n]*` to exclude newlines.

```
^\s*_.*|.*_\s*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bfhNUe/1)

```js
const regex = /^\s*_.*|.*_\s*$/;
[
  "Sample welcome text_",
  "Sample _welcome_ _text_",
  "Sample_welcome_text"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookbehind and lookahead for either whitespace or start/end of string, and reference the word in capture group 1: `(.*?)`

```js
const regex = /(?<=\s|^)_(.*?)_(?=\s|$)/gs;
[
  "Sample welcome text_",
  "Sample _welcome_ _text_",
  "Sample_welcome_text"
].forEach(str => {
  let matches = [...str.matchAll(regex)].map(m => m[1]);
  console.log(str, '=>', matches);
});
```

If you are concerned about Safari not supporting lookbehind, you can turn the lookbehind into capture group, and reference capture group 2 instead:

```js
const regex = /(\s|^)_(.*?)_(?=\s|$)/gs;
[
  "Sample welcome text_",
  "Sample _welcome_ _text_",
  "Sample_welcome_text"
].forEach(str => {
  let matches = [...str.matchAll(regex)].map(m => m[2]);
  console.log(str, '=>', matches);
});
```

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex